# One on One Mapping of two lists to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have two lists like:
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2]

Now, I want to one on one map just like this:

```
colA colB
1     1
1     2
1     3
2     1
2     2
2     3
```

I have tried this but didn't work

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in a:
    df["A"] = i
    
    for j in b:
        df["B"] = j
```

Comment: When you do `df['A'] = some_value` you assign all the values in the column to that value. However, your dataframe is empty, so "setting all values in the column" to a given value results in 0 values being set. [The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54883211/15497888) of the linked duplicate will work, just replace the `a` and `b` lists in that question with the ones you would like to use. `df = pd.DataFrame(product(b, a), columns=['colA', 'colB'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and the [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

pd.DataFrame(product(b, a), columns=['colA', 'colB'])
```

output:

```
   colA  colB
0     1     1
1     1     2
2     1     3
3     2     1
4     2     2
5     2     3
```